# Querying in MySQL on table with no Unique Key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to query a database that I have in MySQL. I need to union this with another query from a traditional table, so I'd like it all done in php. Here is how I'm currently doing this, which I think may be very inefficient.

This is a sample of the database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/874e19/3

This is how I'm selecting the information:

```
$device = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
DISTINCT
serial
FROM
device
ORDER BY 
edit_date 
DESC
")or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = $device->fetch_assoc()) {

$serial = $row['serial'];

$device_data = $mysqli->query('SELECT
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'device_name\' AND serial = \''. $serial . '\')) as hostname,
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'unit\' AND serial = \''. $serial . '\')) as unit,
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'version\' AND serial = \''. $serial . '\')) as version,
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'lan_ip\' AND serial = \'' . $serial .'\')) as location_ip,
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'wan_ip\' AND serial = \'' . $serial .'\')) as wan_ip,
(SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = \'status\' AND serial = \'' . $serial .'\')) as status
')or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *"a NoSQL database that I have in MySQL"* wait... what? That all looks very SQL to me. No trace of anything one would consider "NoSQL" anywhere.

Comment: Correct. I was mistaken, this isn't NoSQL. However, the problem persists whatever you want to call it.

Comment: When you agree that this has nothing to do with NoSQL, then please edit the question and rewrite it fix this.

Comment: If the first query returns no rows, then `$device_data` will be unassigned. If it contains more than one row, `$device_data` will be overwritten by the results of a couple of expensive queries, and you will get only the last result.

Comment: But rather than posting just the query, you might want to explain the meaning of these tables and what it is that you actually want to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that in just one query for best performance and simplicity. Something like this two solutions should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.serial, d.data_value AS hostname, d1.data_value AS unit, d2.data_value AS version, d3.data_value AS lan_ip, d4.data_value AS wan_ip, d5.data_value AS status
  FROM device d
  LEFT JOIN device d1 ON d.serial = d1.serial AND d1.data_type = 'unit'
  LEFT JOIN device d2 ON d.serial = d2.serial AND d2.data_type = 'version'
  LEFT JOIN device d3 ON d.serial = d3.serial AND d3.data_type = 'lan_ip'
  LEFT JOIN device d4 ON d.serial = d4.serial AND d4.data_type = 'wan_ip'
  LEFT JOIN device d5 ON d.serial = d5.serial AND d5.data_type = 'status'
WHERE d.data_type = 'device_name'
ORDER BY d.edit_date DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.serial, d.data_value AS hostname,
    (SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = 'unit' AND serial = d.serial)) AS unit,
    (SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = 'version' AND serial = d.serial)) AS version,
    (SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = 'lan_ip' AND serial = d.serial)) AS location_ip,
    (SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = 'wan_ip' AND serial = d.serial)) AS wan_ip,
    (SELECT data_value FROM device WHERE (data_type = 'status' AND serial = d.serial)) AS status)
  FROM device d 
WHERE d.data_type = 'device_name'
ORDER BY d.edit_date DESC;
```